# App crush while running a simple ball app

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to launch a very basic app - a ball that should bounce on the screen but I am getting an error while trying to launch app on device.

Here's my code, I may have some errors but please explain to me what are they and how could I fix them, I'm new to android development..

```
    public class Ball {

    float x;
    float y;

    boolean movingRight;
    boolean movingBottom;

    float screenWidth;
    float screenHeight;

    public Ball(float x, float y, float screenWidth, float screenHeight) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
        this.screenHeight = screenHeight - 150;
        this.movingBottom = false;
        this.movingRight = false;


    }

    public void move() {
        if (movingRight)
            this.x++;
        else
            this.x--;

        if (movingBottom)
            this.y++;
        else
            this.y--;

        if (this.x >= this.screenWidth)
            this.movingRight = false;

        else if (this.x <= 1)
            this.movingRight = true;


        if (this.y >= this.screenHeight)
            this.movingBottom = false;
        else if (this.y <= 1)
            this.movingBottom = true;
    }


    public float getX(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView{
    private Ball ball;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    Paint paint;

    public Paint getBallPaint()
    {
        if(paint == null)
        {
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        }
        return this.paint;
    }
    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                draw(c);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                       int width, int height) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawCircle(ball.x,ball.y,15,getBallPaint());
    }
}

    public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
        private MySurfaceView view;
        private boolean running = false;

        public GameLoopThread(MySurfaceView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            running = run;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                Canvas c = null;
                try {
                    c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                        view.draw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        Ball ball;

        MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;
        GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            int screenWidth;
            screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int screenHeight;
            screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            ball = new Ball(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2, screenWidth,screenHeight);
            gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(mySurfaceView);
            gameLoopThread.start();
            mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
            setContentView(mySurfaceView);
        }
```

Comment: Are you also new to debugging?

Comment: Add a logcat if you want real answers.  Better yet, do some searching on the exception before posting here.

Comment: Ok, Ill search how to debug and do it.
But I have another question. 
I have a surfaceview with its own runnable and all and it draws a ball on a screen. I have another thread which moves the ball.
How can i initialize between the main UI thread (which draws the ball) and the thread which moves the ball?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell if there are other errors but most obvious one is that you are using mySurfaceView before you have created it.

You should change initialization order to:

```
        mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mySurfaceView);
        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(mySurfaceView);
        gameLoopThread.start();
```